# How to exchange multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010, multiple-columns

Using Microsoft Excel 2010, I have a spreadsheet containing data from 5 different datafiles (each having 14 columns, so 70 columns together). What I need to do, is to sort these columns in this fashion: 1.,15.,29.,43.,57.,2.,16.,...etc.

Basically, I need first columns from 5 datafiles in a row, then second columns etc. Is there some way in Excel how to write this sequence? I tried substitute, address and indirect, but without any results. I can write it manually, but as I need it with different spreadsheets as well, I thought it might be handy to have an actual command for it.

Comment: What format are the data files? Show us what you tried and there may be a way to steer you onto the right course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using the following formula in your final spreadsheet:

```
=INDEX({"Sheet1";"Sheet2";"Sheet3";"Sheet4";"Sheet5"},MOD(COLUMN()-1,5)+1)
```

If you paste this formula on each column of you final spreadsheet, it will cycle from `Sheet1` to `Sheet5` from column `A` to `E` etc. You write the name of your files and the spreadsheet target in it, and this will serve as the base of the formula reference.

The formula works as follows: with the modulo applied on the `COLUMN` index value, we get numbers from 1 to 5 that are used by `INDEX` to get one item from the [constant array](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/more-arrays-introducing-array-constants-in-excel-HA001087291.aspx).

Now that we get the base of the cycling through the spreadsheets, we need now a group of 5 columns A, then 5 columns B, etc. We use this:

```
=QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1, 5)+1
```

Now we can combine them with `ADDRESS`:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1, 5)+1,1,1,INDEX({"Sheet1";"Sheet2";"Sheet3";"Sheet4";"Sheet5"},MOD(COLUMN()-1,5)+1))
```

If you paste and extend the formula on range A1:J3, you will get these addresses:

```
Sheet1!$A$1 Sheet2!$A$1 Sheet3!$A$1 Sheet4!$A$1 Sheet5!$A$1 Sheet1!$B$1 Sheet2!$B$1 Sheet3!$B$1 Sheet4!$B$1 Sheet5!$B$1
Sheet1!$A$2 Sheet2!$A$2 Sheet3!$A$2 Sheet4!$A$2 Sheet5!$A$2 Sheet1!$B$2 Sheet2!$B$2 Sheet3!$B$2 Sheet4!$B$2 Sheet5!$B$2
Sheet1!$A$3 Sheet2!$A$3 Sheet3!$A$3 Sheet4!$A$3 Sheet5!$A$3 Sheet1!$B$3 Sheet2!$B$3 Sheet3!$B$3 Sheet4!$B$3 Sheet5!$B$3
```

Eventually we wrap this formula with `INDIRECT` to get the actual data:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1, 5)+1,1,1,INDEX({"Sheet1";"Sheet2";"Sheet3";"Sheet4";"Sheet5"},MOD(COLUMN()-1,5)+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter `1` in `ColumnA`, drag across to `ColumnN` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed. Select all fourteen cells and drag across to `ColumnBR` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed. Sort the columns Smallest to Largest by the row with the added `1` etc.